# Underscore.js externs for Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, google-closure-compiler

I am using [Luke Rodgers' Backbone and Underscore externs](http://www.lukerodgers.ca/2012/05/closure-compiler-externs-files-for-underscore-and-backbone-js/) but cannot work out why `_.extend` is being modified in the compiled output.

For example in Backbone 0.9.2 the following code (193:195):

```
if (defaults = getValue(this, 'defaults')) {
  attributes = _.extend({}, defaults, attributes);
}
```

is compiled to:

```
if(c=r(this,"defaults"))a=f.extend({},c,a);
```

I used the following compile command:

```
java -jar compiler.jar 
     --externs backbone-0.9.2-externs.js 
     --externs underscore-1.3.3-externs.js 
     --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS 
     --js underscore-1.3.3.js  
     --js backbone-0.9.2.js 
     --js_output_file compiled.js
```

If I include another JavaScript file:

```
     --js test.js
```

that contains the following:

```
_.extend({}, {name: 'test'});
```

it is unmodified in `compiled.js`.

Does anyone know why calls to `_.extend` in backbone.js are being modified?

Comment: stupid question - does it work?

Comment: The code above is just a small example to highlight the problem. In my app I get errors: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined", "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined, "Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined", ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad you've found my externs files useful. Off the top of my head, I believe the issue you are encountering is due to the fact that you are both using externs files AND compiling the libraries.

Typically externs files are used when the library is not part of the compilation procedure. Some people may just use pre-compiled versions of (e.g.) jQuery, Underscore, etc., or link to the shared Google libraries to take advantage of pre-cached js, yet still want to make Closure Compiler understand the jQuery and Underscore API, and so they use externs.

If what you're looking for is the explicit type annotations in the Underscore and Backbone libraries, this is a somewhat different problem.

Comment: Ah-ha, I was obviously having an "if I hit it hard enough with a hammer it's bound to work" moment.

So there doesn't appear to be a way to create a single JavaScript file that contains Underscore and Backbone with the Closure Compiler when using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS.